# Spring inject test: Bean is not injected on test

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I've created this custom test configuration:

```
@TestConfiguration
public static class RestTemplateTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public static ApplicationDao applicationDao() {
        ApplicationDao mock = Mockito.mock(ApplicationDao.class);
        // some stuff code
        return mock;
    }
}
```

I've set a breakpoint on `applicationDao`, but it's never reached, and therefore mock is never injected.

**EDIT**

`ApplicationDao` is an `@Repository` annotated class:

```
@Repository
public interface ApplicationDao extends MongoRepository<Application, String> {
```

So, how could I override this `@Repository` annotated `AplicationDao`?

Currently, I'm getting this message when spring starts:

> Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=applicationDao,declaringClass=net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.functional.references.GroupReferencesTest$RestTemplateTestConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'applicationDao' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you use static class and static methods?

Comment: It's a nested class

Answer (score 1):

If your method `applicationDao()` is never called it means that your spring boot is not scanning the package where `RestTemplateTestConfiguration` is located.

The simplest solutions is to move the configuration under the same package (or its children) as the one that contains the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

OBS : This rule applies even though the configuration is in the `test` directory instead of `main`.

Another solution is to add `@ComponentScan` with the configuration package or to use `@Import(RestTemplateTestConfiguration.class)` at your spring boot test level.

SUGGESTION:
For your problem you can use:

```
@Mock
ApplicationDao applicationDao;
```

and if you have another service that uses this one to use:

```
@InjectMock
MyService myService;
```

Comment: I've look at logs and I've just realized it's getting me this message: `Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=applicationDao,declaringClass=net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.functional.references.GroupReferencesTest$RestTemplateTestConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'applicationDao' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.` Is it telling you some more information?

Comment: I've added a suggestion for your issue, please mention if you need to override the bean definition instead.